# JavaScript: How to generate table of random letters with certian words randomly hidden throughout?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to put an array of words inside a table thats filled with random letters.

I just want to be simple where the words are positioned horizontally so that children can easily find them.

Example of expected output:

```
o r a n g e a
d h j d k k t
b e e r g h k
w r t u i o p
a f t y u o j
```

My current code:

```
  function randomWord() {
        var cols = 5; 
        var rows = 5; 
        var html = ""; 
        var words = ['apple', 'beer'],

        for(var i =0; i <= rows; i++) { 
            html += '<tr>'; 
            for(var h=0; h<= cols; h++) { 
               var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'; 
               var random = parseInt(Math.random()*characters.length);
               var letter = characters.charAt(random); //returning random letter
               html += '<td>' + letter + '</td>'; 
            } 
            html += '</tr>'; 
        }

        document.getElementById('wsBox').innerHTML += html;
    }
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody id="wsBox">
    </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="randomWord()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I notice that your code makes no use of the array of words. This seems strange to me, since they're what matters and random letters are merely there to obscure them. Have you considered viewing the words as rectangles? Either tall or wide, you could then fit these rectangles inside the playing area before filling any remaining gaps with junk letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to implement the following algrothim:

1. initalise a 2D array of randomised characters from your alphabet and, write the words to hide into the that 2D array directly
2. randomise the order of the rows in the 2D array, which will randomly distribute word placement throughout the rows of the resulting table
3. build the actual table from the 2D array data

In code this could be expressed as:

```js
function randomWord() {
  var cols = 5;
  var rows = 5;
  var words = ['apple', 'beer', 'cow'];
  var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ';

  // Array to store all letters for resulting table
  const data = [];
  
  // Populate 2D-array with characters
  for (var i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {

    // Array to store letters for current row      
    const row = [];

    // Populate this row with random letters
    for (var h = 0; h <= cols; h++) {
      const letterIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
      const letter = alphabet[letterIdx];
      row.push(letter);
    }

    // While there are words to be read, insert those
    if (words.length > 0) {
    
      // Current word to insert
      const word = words.pop();          
      // If there's space to horizontally offset the word, then 
      // caluclate a random offset. Add 1 because loop range is 
      // 0 < i <= col
      const offsetIdx = Math.floor((1 + cols - word.length) * Math.random());
      
      for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {          
        if(i + offsetIdx < cols) {              
          // Write each letter of the word into the 2D-array
          row[i + offsetIdx] = word[i];
        }
      }
    }

    data.push(row);
  }

  // Randomise the order of rows in the 2D-array
  data.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

  const table = document.getElementById('wsBox');
  
  // Clear the tablet
  table.innerHTML = '';
  
  // Iterate both dimensions of the table and build table from 2D-array
  data.forEach((rowData, i) => {
    const row = table.insertRow(i);

    rowData.forEach((cellData, j) => {
      const cell = row.insertCell(j);
      cell.innerText = cellData;
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="wsBox">
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="randomWord()">Click me</button>
```